# PowerShell Invoking .PS1 File without specifying location even though its in another directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, autosys

I have a script that I would like to invoke using autosys, but I want to invoke it without specifying the location of the script. Do I place the directory of the script in the %PATH% Location ?

Comment: Yes, you can try that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with autosys, but it seems to me that when dealing with scheduled/automated tasks anything you can do to make your intentions explicit and predictable is a good thing, so why would you want to rely on `%PATH%` resolution instead of just specifying the known location of the script?  Also, which of the three versions of PowerShell you've tagged is the one you're actually using?

Comment: Currently using 4.0, I want to invoke it without a location because its easier for devs to do it making life simpler

Comment: @abdullahalhamidi - the problem with "making life simpler" is that you are doing so in the _short term_ while sacrificing simplicity in the long term. [*frown*] ///// one strongly stated programming mantra is ... _avoid undefined values whenever possible_. if you CAN, then you should make the path explicit. if you cannot do so, then add your script to one of the usual `%path%` locations OR add your script storage path to your `%path%`.